# UPDATE the Columns of the Rows of the SELECT output

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

### TABLE fruit

```
name      family       ordered           ordered_on
apple      tree         false             null
banana     tree         false             null
mango      tree         false             null
```

### TABLE basket

```
name      family       ordered           ordered_on
apple      tree         false             null
banana     tree         false             null
```

I have a Select query comparing two tables using Except.
Now I need to change few columns of Table fruit of row mango.

I tried the below query and it updated all the rows in the fruits table:

```
UPDATE fruits 
   SET ordered='true', ordered_on = '08/14/2019' 
  FROM (SELECT LEFT name, family 
          FROM fruits 
        EXCEPT 
        SELECT name, family 
          FROM basket) AS subquery
```

### I expect the output:

### Table fruit:

```
mango      tree         true             08/14/2019
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `with..as` clause composed of your query in it, and match through `family` and `name` columns :

```
with t0 as
( 
 select name, family from fruits except select name, family from basket
)
update fruits t1
   set ordered='true', ordered_on = '2019-08-14'
  from t0
 where t1.name = t0.name and t1.family = t0.family;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=4df036391dd57d838011086d6a7f7536)</kbd>

Comment: What if I have to cast the data type of Col name on Table fruit to text.

Comment: Nothing changes, you can try it on the Demo @MrKarma4u

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with NOT EXISTS:

```
update fruits f
set ordered = true, ordered_on = '2019-08-14'
where not exists (
  select 1 from basket
  where name = f.name and family = f.family
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6gzDvctWFyRyMWWequD8EG/0).
Results:

```
| name   | family | ordered | ordered_on |
| ------ | ------ | ------- | -----------|
| apple  | tree   | false   |            |
| banana | tree   | false   |            |
| mango  | tree   | true    | 2019-08-14 |
```